# Semantic Versioning (Caret)

Tags: git, versioning, package.json, semantic-versioning, composer-php

I have a question related with the semantic versioning in projects where are in "beta" phase.

Imagine that I have a plugin and it's version is 1.1.1-beta.1,
some days before, I upgrade my plugin and then, the new version is 1.1.1-beta.2.

But... this new version has a break change with the 1.1.1-beta.1.

Should I change the version to 2.0.0-beta.1 or my current version is correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my assumptions...

You currently have a released version of `1.1.0`.  You are working on a patch release, that only makes bug fixes, hence why you are working on a beta version of `1.1.1`.

During the development of those bugs, you introduce a breaking change.  As a result of this breaking change, the next release number should be `2.0.0`.

You only ever change one number at a time with Semantic Versioning, and when you do, all number to the right of that number go to zero.

http://semver.org/

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've copied&pasted the minor and path numbers, my question is related with the major, anyway, you've answered my question. Thank you!